# Kivy: chow to obtain coordinates of FloatLayout center

Tags: python, kivy

I want to draw circle in center of FloatLayout. With my knowledges I obtained only default values for this. Why circle in showed code isn't red? Can You explain me process for obtaining necessary coordinates, please?

```
import kivy
from kivy.config import Config
kivy.config.Config.set('graphics','resizable', False)


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class Scene(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def draw_circle(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Color=(1,0,0)
            circ = Ellipse(pos = (self.center_x, self.center_y), size=(20,20))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):    
        pass

class Game(BoxLayout):
    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        but1 = Button(text = 'button 1')
        self.add_widget(but1)

        self.scene =  Scene()
        self.add_widget(self.scene)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        game.scene.draw_circle()

        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the size of your float layout when you create it.

```
self.scene =  Scene(size=(300, 300))
```

Then your circle should be at the center of the `FloatLayout` dimensions.

I also think `FloatLayout` is better used with `size_hint` and `pos_hint` instead of fixed coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `draw_circle` with `Clock` to make sure the layout is completely initiated first.
Then make sure to create your color like this `Color(1, 0, 0)`. Not `Color = ()`

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','resizable', False)    
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Scene(FloatLayout):

    def draw_circle(self, dt):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)
            circ = Ellipse(pos = (self.center_x, self.center_y), size=(20,20))


class Game(BoxLayout):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        but1 = Button(text = 'button 1')
        self.add_widget(but1)

        self.scene =  Scene()
        self.add_widget(self.scene)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Clock.schedule_once(game.scene.draw_circle) # call draw_circle on next frame

        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```